# How to deal with different model types

Tags: object-oriented, python

Background:  I need to render the same information in two text formats.  To do this, I have a set of model classes that store the appropriate information.  I then need to render that same information in two different ways.

Each model has a list of 'actions'.  Different actions have different attributes.

How do I handle this in my rendering code without a switch on the type of action?  I'm working on the assumption that a switch statement on object type is a bad thing.

```
if isinstance(action, ActionOne):
    render_action_one(action)
elif isinstance(action, ActionTwo):
    render_action_two(action)
```

The action classes, being part of the model, don't know how to do this rendering.

Edit: This happens to be in Python, but I don't think that matters so much here.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: model.RenderAction()

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but take a look on the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau that looks promising.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You don't. you are doing it wrong.

Instead of render methods on your model, have multiple Views for the same model.

Comment: That's basically what I'm trying to do.  There's more than one type of Action in the model.  How do I associate the correct View with the type of Action when I come to render it?

Comment: you will have to expand on the language and frameworks you are using. there shouldnt be a problem just calling model.action()

Comment: Hm.  Python, no framework.

Comment: urg. upgrade to .net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986/whats-a-good-lightweight-python-mvc-framework